Why does $\int_{0}^{1}a\sin\left(a\sin^{-1}x\right)dx=\frac{a^{2}-a\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}a\right)}{a^{2}-1}$?
I was playing around with the function $f(x)=a\sin\left(a\sin^{-1}x\right)$ on Desmos and noticed that the integral of $f$ from $x=0$ to $x=1$ followed the pattern: $\frac{a}{a+1},\frac{a^{2}}{a^{2}-1},\frac{a}{a-1},\frac{a^{2}}{a^{2}-1},...$ for integer values of $a$. I found a formula $\frac{a^{2}-a\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}a\right)}{a^{2}-1}$ to represent this pattern and found that it gave values that numerically matched with the values of the integral for non-integer $a$. However, I can't figure out how to solve the integral analytically.
How can I show that $\int_{0}^{1}a\sin\left(a\sin^{-1}x\right)dx=\frac{a^{2}-a\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}a\right)}{a^{2}-1}$?

Do you think it is true for non-integer $a,$ as well, or just want a proof for integer $a?$

@ThomasAndrews Yes, I think it is true for non-integer $a$ as well

Get rid of $\sin^{-1}x$ by setting $t = \sin^{-1} x$, so $x = \sin t$ with $0 \leq x \leq 1$ being the same as $0 \leq t \leq \pi/2$. In terms of $t$, the desired formula is the same as
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(at)\cos(t)\,dt = \frac{a - \sin((\pi/2)a)}{a^2-1}.
$$
This equation is a routine calculation using integration by parts twice.  It's the same way you would calculate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(4t)\cos(t)\,dt$ using integration by parts twice.

Use the substitution $x=\sin\theta$
$$I[a] = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} a\sin a\theta \cos\theta\:d\theta$$
and then integrate by parts twice
$$= -\cos a\theta \cos\theta\Biggr|_0^\frac{\pi}{2} - \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos a\theta \sin\theta\:d\theta$$
$$= 1 - \frac{1}{a}\sin a\theta\sin\theta\Biggr|_0^\frac{\pi}{2} + \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{a}\sin a\theta \cos\theta \:d\theta$$
$$\implies I = 1 - \frac{1}{a}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}a\right) + \frac{1}{a^2}I$$
Rearranging algebraically gives you your desired expression
$$\boxed{I[a] = \frac{a^2-a\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}a\right)}{a^2-1}}$$
Technically this path has no solution for the $a=1$ case (since the $I$'s above would cancel out leaving me with no quantity to solve for) but you can do that case separately
$$I[1] = \int_0^1 x\:dx = \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{1+1}$$
and show that the above solution's hole can be filled in continuously with the limit as $a\to 1$ because the limit matches the real computed value.
